# Send an array as a parameter in a Alamofire POST request

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, alamofire, aws-api-gateway

My app is currently using AWS API Gateway and Alamofire to access different lambda functions that act as my backend.

I have the need to send an array as one of the parameters to one of those API end points, for that I am using the following code:

```
        var interests : [String]
        interests = globalInterests.map({ (interest) -> String in
            return interest.id!
        })

        // Parameters needed by the API
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "name" : name,
            "lastName" : lastName,
            "interests" : interests
        ]


        // Sends POST request to the AWS API
        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in

            // Process Response
            switch response.result {

            case .Success:

                print("Sucess")

            case .Failure(let error):
                 print(error)
            }
        }
```

But that is not working because of the array is not being recognized by the API, but if I create a "static" array

```
let interests = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Everything works as it is supposed to.

How can I fix this situation given that the array of interests come from another part of the code, how should I declare it or construct it?

A friend managed to accomplish this in Android using an

```
ArrayList<String>
```

EDIT:

Printing the parameters array shows me this:

```
["name":test, "interests": <_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7b05ac00>( 103, 651, 42), "lastName": test]
```

Comment: What is return by  return interests.id! ?

Comment: I think the 'interests' is always empty and the code that computes interests does not make sense to me. You have an empty array declared, and you try to map over it!. Can you clarify that part?

Comment: Edited the question, I made I mistake when copying the code. After the map the array is not empty and is an [(String)] with 3 values

Comment: Any update on that problem ?

Comment: Use [String: Any] instead of [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AnyObject can only represent class type. In Swift, Array and Dictionary are struct, instead of the class type in many other languages. The struct cannot be described into AnyObject, and this is why Any comes in. Besides of class, Any can be utilized in all other types too, including struct and enum.

Therefore whenever we type cast array or dictionary to AnyObject _TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray error occurs.So we have to Any instead of AnyObject.

```
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "name" : name,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "interests" : interests
    ]
```

Answer (score 16):

By using NSJSONSerialization to encode JSON, you can build your own NSURLRequest for using it in Alamofire, here's a **Swift 3** example:

```
    //creates the request        

    var request = URLRequest(url: try! "https://api.website.com/request".asURL())

    //some header examples

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE", 
                     forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //parameter array

    let values = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

    //now just use the request with Alamofire

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in

        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:

            //success code here

        case .failure(let error):

            //failure code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: request.setValue("application/json;charset=UTF-8",forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have just declared the array and not initialized it. That makes the interest array as nil even if u try to insert the data. Try writing

```
var interests = [String]()
```

instead of

```
var interests : [String]
```

Answer (score 0):

let ValueArray = ["userid": name,"password":password]

pass ValueArray [parameters: ValueArray] also verify the encoding accepted by the API.

Comment: This is indeed the way the parameters array is constructed but the problem comes when trying to send an array as one of those parameters, when working only with strings everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with duplicated ids in the array. The code behind the API threw an exception that was not being send back as an error.

All the other answers are correct, I tested them after finding the problem and everything worked so I am going to up-vote them.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? It's not a problem of duplicate entries. I also get the same result as you. `"People": <_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7f7f565d1440>(
3,
23105
)`.

Comment: In my case the problem was on the server side and not an Alamofire problem. I would recommend you open a new question with more details about what is going on.