# send JSON array as parameter using alamofire in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to send this data (JSON format) as parameter using Alamofire to swift 3:

```
[ {"type":"confirm",
"refKey":"123456789",
"quantity": "1"} ]
```

But I can't convert it as parameter data because the accepted data type is `[String:Any]`

How can I pass the needed parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I found my Answer in this post:
[Send an array as a parameter in a Alamofire POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563371/send-an-array-as-a-parameter-in-a-alamofire-post-request)

Using JSONSerialization and URLRequest of Alamofire to send the data in HTTPBody.

```
    //creates the request        

var request = URLRequest(url: try! "https://api.website.com/request".asURL())

//some header examples

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE", 
                 forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//parameter array

let values = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

//now just use the request with Alamofire

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in

    switch (response.result) {
    case .success:

        //success code here

    case .failure(let error):

        //failure code here
    }
}
```

Author: mourodrigo

Comment: Thanks for the mention! =)