# Creating a JSON Array in Swift with and without SwiftyJSON for use Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have the following code for use with the ShipEngine API.  The API wants a JSON Array.  I thought I had the correct Swift Syntax, but I get an error result that says the type requires a JSON Array.  I also tried SwiftyJSON but i get a different compiler error with the alamofire line.

The returned error is:

```
  "errors" : [
{
  "error_code" : "",
  "message" : "addresses.city_locality: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShipEngine.Core.DTO.Address.AddressDTO]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'city_locality', line 1, position 17."
}
```

]

The code I am using is this:

```
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "api-key": "API-KEY_HERE"
    ]

    // not using SwiftyJSON
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "name": "Mickey and Minnie Mouse",
            "phone": "714-781-4565",
            "company_name": "The Walt Disney Company",
            "address_line1": "500 South Buena Vista Street",
            "city_locality": "Burbank",
            "state_province": "CA",
            "postal_code": "91521",
            "country_code": "US"
    ]

    let url = "https://api.shipengine.com/v1/addresses/validate"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
                print ("return as JSON using swiftyJson is: \(swiftyJson)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print ("error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```

If I use SwiftyJSON and change my parameters declaration to this:

```
        let parameters: JSON =  [
        "name": "Mickey and Minnie Mouse",
        "phone": "714-781-4565",
        "company_name": "The Walt Disney Company",
        "address_line1": "500 South Buena Vista Street",
        "city_locality": "Burbank",
        "state_province": "CA",
        "postal_code": "91521",
        "country_code": "US"
    ]
```

The I get a compiler error which says:

*Extra argument 'method' in call*

on the following line:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

Any help from someone that can tell me how to construct the array would be greatly appreciated.  I have tried various formats and done numerous searches, but am having no luck... as you probrably guessed I am a swift newbie!!

Thanks for the help!

Oh one last thing that may help a person assist me, this is from the ShipEngine site for use of this api call:

```
    curl https://api.shipengine.com/v1/addresses/validate -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "api-key: ElJkhJuQIRoFq/kDEblco4LpZqRCdYNIoAVG7SywSXw" \
  -d '
[
  {
    "name": "Mickey and Minnie Mouse",
    "phone": "714-781-4565",
    "company_name": "The Walt Disney Company",
    "address_line1": "500 South Buena Vista Street",
    "city_locality": "Burbank",
    "state_province": "CA",
    "postal_code": "91521",
    "country_code": "US"
  }
]'
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697127/4601900

Comment: Yes, but if you look at my format and what is shown at that link they are the same, at least I see no difference.  That shows this format:     let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "name" : name,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "interests" : interests
    ]  That is exactly what I have with the exception of the variables.  But Alamo still tell me it requires a valid JSON array.